# Vaadin Table: load data only on click of button

Tags: java, lazy-loading, vaadin

My table have a big query, so I want to make the user filter some fields before displaying the table data.

It's possible to make the table get the data only on the click of some button? Actually when I load my view the table already get the data, this is made by the `PagedTable` or the `LazyBeanContainer`(I'm using [Lazy Container](https://github.com/ondrej-kvasnovsky/lazy-container) to paginate my table)?

Comment: @quinxorin Do you know Vaadin?

Comment: No, I unfortunately do not. Wait, java! Not javascript. Oops, misread the tag.

Comment: add a `Button.ClickListener` instead of loading data when loading the view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first you can just init the Table

```
Table table = new Table()
```

You should then define a container for your table (I suggest you to use BeanItemContainer)

```
BeanItemContainer<YourObject> container = new BeanItemContainer<YourObject>(YourObject.class);
```

At last, you should fill the container in the Button.ClickListener

```
Button button = new Button("Button", new Button.ClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                table.setContainerDataSource(container);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to set generated columns in the creation of my view:

```
String[] columns = new String[]{"id","myField"}

for(String col : columns) {
  table.addGeneratedColumn(col, new ColumnGenerator() {
    public Object generateCell(Table source, Object itemId, Object columnId) {
      return "";
    }
  });
}
```

This results in an empty table, but with columns and labels. Then in the button click, I set the container and remove the old columns:

```
for(String col : columns) {
  table.removeGeneratedColumn(col);
}
table.setContainerDataSource(myContainer);
...
```